# Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string. Received: {}

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I upgraded my angular to 1.5 and i am getting this error. Here is the code which is inside my controller

```js
var reportURL = $rootScope.hostUrl + API_VERSION + "/runreports/" +
                encodeURIComponent(scope.reportName);
reportURL += "?output-type=" + 
             encodeURIComponent(scope.formData.outputType) + 
             "&tenantIdentifier=" + $rootScope.tenantIdentifier + 
             "&locale=" + scope.optlang.code + "&dateFormat=" + scope.df;

var inQueryParameters = buildReportParms();
if (inQueryParameters > "") reportURL += "&" + inQueryParameters;

// Allow untrusted urls for the ajax request.

reportURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(reportURL);
http.get(reportURL, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    var contentType = headers('Content-Type');
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: contentType});
    var fileContent = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    // Pass the form data to the iframe as a data url.
    scope.baseURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileContent);
  });
```

Since Angular 1.4.9, the $http service only accepts pure strings as URLs. If I pass in an object that has a toString() method, $http raises an exception

What could be the workaround for this code ?

Comment: The `.success` method is deprecated. Use the `params` property of the `config` object to encode search parameters. Use `responseType: 'blob'` instead of converting an arraybuffer to a blob. Use `.toString()` if it is needed.